# How do I write a Luigi workflow for loading data into Redshift from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, luigi

Does Luigi have support for me to execute the entire flow?

The flow would be something like this:
Dumping MySQL data to S3, then moving the data to Redshift using the Copy command.

Can I execute the above workflow using Luigi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you can do anything that you can do with a python script, in Luigi, since you can write that python code in the `run()` method of Luigi tasks, which means there is no real limits actually.

See the Luigi docs for tasks, and in particular the run() method, for more information: http://luigi.readthedocs.org/en/stable/tasks.html#task-run

So, the remaining question is then how to access RedShift and MySQL from python itself, but that is a separate question, for which I think googling around for a good guide or tutorial is the best option.